# Media queries not working as expected

Tags: css

I have a website that I want to make responsive for mobile use. So I installed bourbon and neat in my app and imported all the files in my `application.sass`

```
@import "bourbon"
@import "neat"
@import "grid-settings"

@import "mobile"
@import "desktop"
```

The `grid-settings` looks like this,

```
@import "neat-helpers"

// Define your breakpoints
$mobile:  new-breakpoint(max-width 480px)
$desktop: new-breakpoint(min-width 481px)
```

My idea was to create to sass files, one for mobile and one for desktop,

so in my `mobile.sass` I have,

```
body, html
  @include media($mobile)
```

And for my `desktop.sass` I have,

```
body, html
  @include media($desktop)
```

But when I check the page and change the browser size to 300px width or 1300px width the content stays the same.

If I inspect an element I can see both styles from the mobile and the desktop file but desktop css overrides the mobile style.

So in this example the top styling is used (desktop) and the bottom styling is striped through (inactive).

```
media="all"
.container-wrapper .another-wrapper .movie_container {
    width: 11.5%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
media="all"
.container-wrapper .another-wrapper .movie_container {
    width: 23%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 1%;
    transition: all 0.5s;
```

Comment: Instead of writing your own media query for this, I would use a responsive framework like Bootstrap, Foundation or w3.css

Comment: full versions of `desktop.sass` or `mobile.sass` would really help... or even better, a working snippet/fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand some things of your question, for example, what's `media = all` means in your css?

Media queries are `@at-rules` that will be enabled when the given condition returns `true`, basically, are similar to a simple **if statement** that you can find in every other programming language.

Example:

```css
.example {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 400ms all linear;
}

.example:before {
  display: block;
  padding: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .example {
    background: lightseagreen;
  }
  
  .example:before {
    content: '@media(max-width: 400px)';
  }
}

@media (min-width: 401px) {
  .example {
    background: lightcoral;
  }
  
  .example:before {
    content: '@media(min-width: 401px)';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
</div>
```

Comment: Apparently you can't just create two files. One for mobile, one for desktop and add the media-queries the body attribute of those files. Seemed like an easy solution to me. `    body, html

      @include media($desktop)

        height: 100%

        min-height: 100%

        background-color: rgb(21, 38, 53)

      @include media($mobile)

        background-color: green` this works. So it's all good.